# Retrieving what object was picked in a spinner

Tags: android, android-studio

So I looked in the spinner api but it says I event handle using an AdapterView but I never created an adapted. I created the array in string.xml and then I retrieved using 
Android:entries =  @array/arrayname

So how do I retrieve what the user picked in the spinner without the Adapter being created? Or am I looking at this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What Google means by implementing an **AdapterView** is that you have to implement its **OnItemSelectedListener** interface on your activity such as:

```
public class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    ...

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {
        // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
        // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Another interface callback
    }
}
```

and you have to set the event listener for that spinner as:

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Here's a full example:

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    //Spinner
    private Spinner spinner;
    //The array that will store the spinner items
    private ArrayList<String> list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Create the spinner and add its listener
        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Spinner items, stored as a String array
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Item 1");
        list.add("Item 2");
        list.add("Item 3");
        list.add("Item 4");

        //To populate the spinner with a list of choices, you need to specify a SpinnerAdapter in your Activity or Fragment
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
        //Set the adapter to the spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        //To Get the selected item:
        //Since the spinner items are stored inside an array
        //we can get the selected item text such as item.get(position)
        Toast.makeText(this, list.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**activity_main** XML Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:background="#CCC"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: how do I have a string contain what the user picks for the spinner    String string = spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); ?

Comment: Try this String text = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

Comment: The spinner is an array of string objects do I still need to convert because the spinner is of spinner objects or no?

Comment: Basically you passed a string array to set up the spinner, and `onItemSelected()` gives you the pos for the item in that array that was picked.

Comment: or getSelectedItem().toString() will give you the text you selected

Comment: I have added a full example to my answer.